# nginx and php-fpm performance cpu bound

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, php-fpm

in peak hours our server is cpu bound. we are hitting 100% cpu. using php5-fpm and nginx on a large ec2 instance. to serve around 50 million requests per day. 
we are using this server to serve JSON results.

i want to profile our server to detect any places where we may be able to optimise our cpu usage. but most benchmarking tools record response times and not resource use.

are there any tools that will determine cpu usage per transaction?

Comment: Which operating system ?

Comment: OS:Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: 500+ requests a second (and I'm guessing that bursts to much higher at times) doesn't sound too bad for a single server. Have you considered something like nginx microcaching to reduce load on the PHP tier?

Comment: What have you already done to reduce CPU usage?

Comment: In case you don't find a way to optimize the configuration of Nginx and PHP I recommend to use [cpulimit](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/) as this will allow you to stop either Nginx or PHP to consume too much resources.

Answer (score 0):

[TraceView](http://www.appneta.com/products/traceview/) from AppNeta has support for PHP and could provide the information you're looking for.

Generally speaking if you haven't done any kernel parameter tuning there's a few things that can be done to help out and there's likely some nginx tuning you could do but those are outside the scope of the question as asked.